# Openpyxl Python Copy From One Excel Sheet&Paste in Existing Individual Workbooks in Subfolders

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a code that copies data based on Column ['A'] cell value from one .xlsx workbook call it my source file and pastes it into the most recently modified .xlsm file in a subfolder. The problem I have is that I have 50 subfolders but my code only works for one, so I am repeating the script 50 times which is not productive. My source file has 2sheets my data is in "Sheet 1", it has 50k+ rows and has columns A:Q. My destination files have multiple sheets but I am pasting into a specific sheet, naming convention for the sheet is same across all 50 files so say sheet name is "Sheet 5". My destination files have header row so am pasting starting from row2, I paste into columns A:Q, it has formula columns R:T. Column A of my source file has multiple cities[DENVER, COLUMBUS, PORTLAND etc], the cities correspond to my destination files, my destination folders looks like this 'c/windows/users/me/documents/mainfolder/DEN' for DENVER, 'c/windows/users/me/documents/mainfolder/COL' for COLUMBUS, 'c/windows/users/me/documents/mainfolder/PRT' for PORTLAND.
Naming convention for the files in the DEN subfolder is
DEN 2022 random string r1.xlsm,
DEN 2022 random string r2.xlsm,
Naming convention for the files in PRT folder is
PRT 2022 random string r2.xlsm,
PRT 2022 random string r3.xlsm etc. My code copies rows from source file where Column A is eg: Denver and pastes starting from row2 into DEN 2022 random string r2.xlsm(most recently modified file). PS:I found the code here on stack, I repurposed it for my project but I need help with how to get the code to work for all 50 subfolders. See my code below:
Sourcefile [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcORD.png)

Destinationfile [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/023jY.png)

```
from copy import copy
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

#my source file
wb_sf= load_workbook(r'C:\Users\me\Documents\Consol\Sourcefile.xlsx')
ws = wb_sf["Sheet 1"]

# my destination file
#find most recently modified file
dest_path = r'c\windows\users\me\documents\mainfolder\DEN'   #DENVER subfolder
latest_file = max(glob.glob(f"{dest_path}/*.xlsm"), key=os.path.getmtime)
#load destination file
wb_df= load_workbook(latest_file, keep_vba = True)
ws2 = wb_df["Sheet 5"]

copyfrom_max_columns = ws.max_column

paste_start_min_row = 1
city_list =  ['DENVER']  #search for DENVER
for city_number, city in enumerate(city_list, 1):  
search_min_row = paste_start_min_row   
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=1, min_row=search_min_row):  
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == city:  
            paste_start_min_row += 1  
            for i in range(copyfrom_max_columns):  
                    # Set the copy and paste Cells
                    copy_cell = cell.offset(column=i)
                    paste_cell = ws2.cell(row=paste_start_min_row, column=i + 1)
                    paste_cell.value = copy_cell.value
                    paste_cell.number_format = copy_cell.number_format

wb_pst.save(latest_file)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I am pasting the code below to help anybodyelse who may be doing similar project. I listed my cities in a list, listed my abbreviations(which also double as my folder name) in a list, I paired the list using zip and used the zip to enumerate and set my subfolder names.

```
wb_sf= load_workbook(r'C:\Users\me\Documents\Consol\Sourcefile.xlsx')
ws = wb_sf["Sheet 1"]


copyfrom_max_columns = ws.max_column


paste_start_min_row = 1

city_list = ['DENVER','COLUMBUS','PORTLAND' ]
ABBR_list =['DEN','COL','PRT']
for city, abbr in zip(city_list, ABBR_list):
    dst_dir_path = 'c/windows/users/me/documents/mainfolder'/{f}/".format(f=(abbr))
latest_file= max(glob.glob(f"{dst_dir_path}/*.xlsm"), key=os.path.getmtime)
    wb_pst = load_workbook(latest_file, keep_vba = True)
    ws2 = wb_pst['Sheet 5']
search_min_row = paste_start_min_row   
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=1, min_row=search_min_row):  
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == city:  
            paste_start_min_row += 1  
            for i in range(copyfrom_max_columns):  
                    # Set the copy and paste Cells
                    copy_cell = cell.offset(column=i)
                    paste_cell = ws2.cell(row=paste_start_min_row, column=i + 1)
                    paste_cell.value = copy_cell.value
                    paste_cell.number_format = copy_cell.number_format

                    # Copy other Cell formatting
                     paste_cell.font = copy(copy_cell.font)
                    paste_cell.alignment = copy(copy_cell.alignment)
                    paste_cell.border = copy(copy_cell.border)
                    paste_cell.fill = copy(copy_cell.fill)

wb_pst.save(latest_file)
```